# Get index of JSON data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, update, json, java, jsonb

I have the next JSON structure in my PosgreSQL:

```
[
 {
  "name": "Ryzen 9",
  "path": "fitnessappmaven\\src\\main\\java\\com\\klaro\\fitnessappmaven\\tempWorkoutIcons\\yoga.png",
  "type": "Gym"
 },
 {
  "name": "2",
  "path": "fitnessappmaven\\src\\main\\java\\com\\klaro\\fitnessappmaven\\tempWorkoutIcons\\workout.png",
  "type": "Street"
 },
 {
  "name": "ya",
  "path": "fitnessappmaven\\src\\main\\java\\com\\klaro\\fitnessappmaven\\tempWorkoutIcons\\yoga.png",
  "type": "Gym"
 }
]
```

For this, I would like to update "name" where "name" is "x". For this I have the next query:

```
UPDATE my_users
SET json_workouts = JSONB_SET(json_workouts,'{0,name}','"Ryzen 9"')
WHERE username='c';
```

However here I need to index which JSON I'd like to remove(in this case 0).
I need to get this index integer automatically.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: If you need not only store/retrieve but also process the data then do not store the data as JSON, parse it into separate table with 3 separate columns of string datatype.

Comment: @Akina Alright, sounds good. By parse the data you mean that I should just delete the current JSONB column and instead I create as many String columns as I need as separate columns( in this case 3)?

Comment: Absolutely correct. The overhead of JSON recreation during retrieving is small enough.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I re-created and I still writing the code to make it work this way. Then I will just loop thru them and get the proper index of each element when I need to retrieve a path by the name for example.

Thank you!